# serial communication between Raspberry and Arduino python

Tags: web, pyserial, uart, serial-communication

I have a problem, I hope some of you can help me.
My current situation:
I have installed a webserver on my Raspberry Pi 3 and I run a website on it. A microcontroller (Arduino ATMega 2560) is serially connected to the Raspberry. I've stored a Send-Char file and a Receive-Char file written with Python on my Raspberry. When I click on a button on my website, i run the Send-File and the File should send a letter via UART to the microcontroller. Before the Raspberry will send the letter, the program should check, if the connection to the controller is given. The program also should write a 'X' to a file "callback.txt", when the connection is given or a 'Y', when there is no connection.
Coming to my problem:
When there is a connection, everything works fine, but when there is no connection, the terminal writes me an error (look at the attached picture).
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you!

```
import serial
from time import sleep

print("SEND CHARACTER")

filestream = -1

filestream = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

if filestream != (-1):
     data = 'X'
else:
     data = 'Y'

text_file = open("callback.txt", "w")
text_file.write(data)
text_file.close()

sleep(0.1)
filestream.write("A")

filestream.close()
```

By the way: sorry for my english skills, but my mother language is german ;)
[error in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er66O.jpg)

Comment: maybe the program will run with exception handling?! but I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Use `try` `exception` statements to check the connection like below.

```
try:
    filestream = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
    data = 'X'
except SerialException:
    data = 'Y'
```